"…while the English speaking world becomes/is becoming ever more complacent"

Millions of people ______ (discover) how to bridge cultures, while the English-speaking world
______ (become) ever more complacent and ____ (cut) down on foreign language learning programmes.

The above is from a grammar exercise and the answers  are "are discovering", "becomes" and "cuts" respectively.
Why there is a difference in the use of tense in the main clause and the subordinate clause? I would use present progressive in both.

That's a good question, using the continuous tense in all three gaps wouldn't be wrong.
But maybe the continuous ‘are discovering’ emphasises how travellers have taken to visiting different continents (bridging cultures) more frequently than in the past, this constant evolution can be expressed using the present continuous.
Until the 1980s–my speculation–Europeans tended to travel within Europe, North Americans generally stuck to visiting places within the USA and so on. For example, I have seen a massive increase of Asian holiday-makers coming to the Italian town where I live in north Italy.
In the subordinate clause, I see no grammatical reason why the Present Perfect or the Continuous was not used here:

…while the English-speaking world has become (or) is becoming complacent…
Note, I intentionally omitted the adverb ‘ever more’ in front of complacent so as to be less distracting.

The Present Perfect works well because it tells the reader the action began in the past and continues to the present. Perhaps the author preferred using the Simple Present because it sounded ‘snappier’ and more immediate. Bear in mind that the Simple Present is also used to express a truth that is either permanent in nature e.g water boils at 100°c, or is true now.

…while the English-speaking world becomes ever more complacent and cuts down on foreign language learning programmes.

For a more in-depth explanation, see British Council: Present Simple

Thanks very much for your answer. I also think present perfect is acceptable, but I find simple present a bit odd here because I remember grammar books say it is used for repeated actions.

@Rick the Presnt Simple is also for general truths such as my username is Mari-Lou A and I am from Italy. I work for a company and I am a mother to an adult son. These actions are not repeated.
